# Configure Oracle instant client to use tnsnames in Ubuntu

Tags: networking, oracle

Trying to get oracle net connections working on Ubuntu 13.10 64bit using [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Oracle%20Instant%20Client) strategy as a basis

I got all this to work perfectly.
I can connect to a remote database using 
sqlplus uid/pwd@server:port/tnsservicename

What that link does not provide is how to set up tnsnames to work with the instant client. There are a bunch of other postings (including one from Oracle itself) that describe how to do this. Basically, you just need to create the /network/admin directory within the $ORACLE_HOME directory, create the tnsnames.ora and sqlnet.ora files and edit them. $TNS_ADMIN also needs to be set

I've done all this but not getting any sort of response using tnsnames.

The error is always:

ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified

Obviously tools like TNSPING are not provided with the instant client so troubleshooting that way is not possible. Also, I added trace options to sqlnet.ora, but -as expected- sqlnet.ora is not found either.

Can anyone help?

Comment: I have the same question!

Comment: Actualy, I got this to work partially because I did get to install Oracle sqldeveloper succesfully. And within that application, TNSNAMES actually works. But only inside sqldevelopper. TNSNAMES as an evironmental viarable still fails. In my case, having a working sqldeveloper gave me all I needed. So (though still stumped) I kinda gave up on solving that. But if you need help getting sqldeveloper running, I'll be happy to share what I did to achieve that. So let me know.

Comment: I managed to make it work now. But I only set TNS_ADMIN to exactly /network/admin folder and use this command to connect: sqlplus uid/pwd@tnsname. Maybe you met another problems.